# Arduino 24LC256 EEPROM only reads 255

Tags: arduino, i2c, eeprom

Print to console is always "255"
I ran code to check for peripherals it saw a device on 0x50.

I don't understand how the EEPROM knows what memory address to read. Neither `requestFrom()` nor `read()` pass a value for the memory address to start reading. Is there an address pointer that is left in position from the write?

Any suggestions?

```c
#include <Wire.h>

int i2cAdd = 0x50;
int memAdd = 100;
int valueWrite = 9;
int valueLength = 1;
int valueRead=0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Start bus");
    Wire.begin();
    delay(100);
  Serial.println("Start Write");
    Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAdd);
    Wire.write(valueWrite);            
    Wire.endTransmission();
    Serial.println("End Write");
    delay(100);
  Serial.println("Start read");
    Wire.requestFrom(i2cAdd, valueLength);
    valueRead = Wire.read();
    Serial.println(valueRead);
    Serial.println("End read");
  } // setup
void loop() {}
```

Comment: “Any suggestion”? Read the data sheet or uses a library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the read or write address as TWO bytes, first the most-significant byte, then the least-significant byte. You aren't specifying which address to read/write.

```
// Write one byte 'valueWrite' to specified address 'memAdd'
Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAdd);
Wire.write((int)(memAdd >> 8));   // write MSB of address to write
Wire.write((int)(memAdd & 0xFF)); // write LSB of address to write
Wire.write(valueWrite);           // write one byte
Wire.endTransmission();

// Specify read address
Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAdd);
Wire.write((int)(memAdd >> 8));   // write MSB of address to read
Wire.write((int)(memAdd & 0xFF)); // write LSB of address to read
Wire.endTransmission();

// read a byte from the specified address
byte rdata = 0xFF;
Wire.requestFrom(i2cAdd, 1);
if (Wire.available())
    rdata = Wire.read();
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a library for arduino I2C EEPROM.
https://github.com/RobTillaart/I2C_EEPROM

Comment: Thanks. I tried that library and found it supported many possibilities and thus was complex. But that is OK, I'm learning as I break it down to save ints, floats and strings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).